# Get a javascript variable indicating current @media type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and Angular.

I currently have an ng-repeat that is set-up like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div ng-if="viewType == 'grid'">
      <div ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts | filter:search" >
         <product-tile-view class="hidden-print col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" product="product" on-selected="deviceSelected(product)" on-compare="compare(product)"></product-tile-view>
         <product-tile-view class="visible-print-block col-xs-4" product="product" on-selected="deviceSelected(product)" on-compare="compare(product)"></product-tile-view>
         <div class="clearfix visible-lg" ng-if="($index + 1) % 6 == 0"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-md" ng-if="($index + 1) % 4 == 0"></div>
         <div class="clearfix visible-sm" ng-if="($index + 1) % 3 == 0"></div>
         <div class="hidden-print clearfix visible-xs" ng-if="($index + 1) % 2 == 0"></div>
         <div class="visible-print-inline clearfix visible-xs" ng-if="($index + 1) % 3 == 0"></div>
      </div>
 ...other unreleated code, divs are closed.
```

This is actually working. To give a brief explanantion of what it is doing:

Depending on the screen size the rows contain 6 items (lg-2), 4 items (md-3), 3 items (sm-4), or 2 items (xs-6). Based on the 12 column width of bootstrap. The clearfix works to reset the row, it's only visible for the appropriate screen size, and the ng-if only adds it to the dom when the index matches the appropriate row.

Depending on the media type (browser or printer), additional bootstrap css is added. This is because bootstrap treats all printer screen size as xs. I want 3 items per row when printing (instead of 2). To accomplish this, I hide the responsive directive when printing, and show a directive with only the col-xs-4 defined. I also hide the original xs clearfix when printing and show one appropriate with the col-xs-4.

All of this is working, but the problem is that these bootstrap media css classes are hiding/showing. Which means behind the scene, there is a significant amount of extra DOM garbage that's being hidden.

To get around to my point. I'm fine with the hidden screen-size clearfixes for now, but I would like to use ng-if instead of the hidden-print / visible-print classes to not write the directive into the DOM twice.

What is the best way to basically get a variable representing the current media type (printer/browser)? I want to use it like `<ng-if currentMediaType == 'print'>` if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you find that is impossible make what you want with css, you can detect the current media using [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). For example

```
var is_screen = window.matchMedia("screen").matches;  //bool 
var is_tv = window.matchMedia("tv").matches;
```

The param is any valid media query expression.

Comment: It is worth noting that this does not work in IE versions before IE10.

Comment: Get it from `window.styleMedia.type` instead --> gives yo the exact type instead of having to check explicitly for each one

Answer (score 2):

You can get it directly from `window.styleMedia.type`

Comment: Please don't do this: `window.styleMedia` is deprecated API draft of `window.matchMedia`, is not implemented in Firefox, and will be removed from the web platform in future. In Chrome, `window.styleMedia.type` doesn't seem to return anything but `"screen"` since `print()` is synchronous (blocking).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in an Angular project I was working on.  It turned out to work pretty well. I was able to show / hide certain directives and markup based on the current bootstrap size.

I'm sure it could be enhanced to support the print / screen media classes.

Here's the core of what I had in place, and you can modify as needed.

In my markup, I added four elements so that I could "watch" them with Angular:

```
<span class="device-xs visible-xs"></span>
<span class="device-sm visible-sm"></span>
<span class="device-md visible-md"></span>
<span class="device-lg visible-lg"></span>
```

Then, in an Angular factory, I created a function that watched for resizes and figured out the Bootstrap size, and stored it for use / retrieval:

(Note that this code also makes use of the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library for the debounce, forEach, and other useful utilities)

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('utility', ['$route', '$window', '$filter', function ($route, $window, $filter) {

  var factory = {};

  // Local store for current window width
  factory.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;

  // Local store for current bootstrap size
  factory.bootstrapSize = '';

  /**
   * Determines which bootstrap kick size we are on (xs, md, etc)
   * NOTE: Relies on the elements being placed on the template somewhere:
   *  .device-xs.visible-xs
   *  .device-sm.visible-sm
   *  .device-md.visible-md
   *  .device-lg.visible-lg
   */
  factory.findKick = function () {
    var kicks = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg'];
    var newkick = '';
    _.forEach(kicks, function (size) {
      var className = '.device-' + size;
      if (factory.isVisible(className)) {
        newkick = size;
        factory.bootstrapSize = size;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if (!newkick) {
       // Do something to log / trap this situation
    }
    return factory.bootstrapSize;
  };

  /**
   * Determines if the passed in element is visible or not
   *
   * @param className
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  factory.isVisible = function (className) {
    return angular.element(className).is(':visible');
  };

  /**
   * Watch for window resizes and executes a debounced function to set the window width
   *
   * @type {Function}
   */
  var w = angular.element($window);
  w.bind('resize', _.debounce(function () {
    factory.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    factory.findKick();
  }, 250));

  // Trigger the bootstrap size immediately on load.
  factory.findKick();

  return factory;

}]);
```